# Deleting/Shrinking HSQLDB lob files

Tags: blob, hsqldb

We're using HSQLDB 2.3.2 and we would like to get rid of the file containing the LOB data. As it is taking a large amount of disk space.

We already changed our LOB columns to VARCHAR. So we don't have any LOB columns anymore.

```
$ ./execute_query.sh "SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, TYPE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYSTEM_COLUMNS WHERE TYPE_NAME LIKE '%LOB%';"
TABLE_NAME  COLUMN_NAME  DATA_TYPE  TYPE_NAME
----------  -----------  ---------  ---------
```

And a list of our HSQLDB files:

```
$ ls -hal
total 88G
drwxr-xr-x 3 admin admin 4.0K Sep 23 13:58 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 admin admin 4.0K Sep  1 09:27 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin 1.5M Apr  9 01:13 hsqldb.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin 2.9G Sep 23 13:53 hsqldb.db.data
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin   16 Sep 23 14:02 hsqldb.db.lck
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin  84G Aug 25 01:52 hsqldb.db.lobs
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin   70 Sep 23 14:00 hsqldb.db.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin   85 Sep 23 13:58 hsqldb.db.properties
-rw-r--r-- 1 admin admin 1.5G Sep 23 13:53 hsqldb.db.script
drwxr-xr-x 2 admin admin 4.0K Sep 23 13:54 hsqldb.db.tmp
```

We would like to get rid of the large `hsqldb.db.lobs` file.

After removing the file, the database does start correctly and seems to run fine. And I can run queries.

But after creating a table with LOB columns and adding data to them the `hsqldb.db.lobs` file gets created again with the original size (although it's a sparse file).

I suspect more magic can be done by modifying certain table values in the SYSTEM_LOBS schema. But I don't think that is a very good practice.

So what's the advised way to either

- Shrink the LOB file so it is much smaller (as we don't use the data)
- Remove the LOB file completely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After removing the file, the database does start correctly and seems
>   to run fine. And I can run queries.

At this point you need to perform CHECKPOINT to reset the lob tables. This works after a workaround described in this post (ignore the compressed setting):

[HSQLDB: enable LOB compression for existing database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31524124/hsqldb-enable-lob-compression-for-existing-database)

Comment: That worked perfectly! And after creating new blob data the file is small again.